# Auto versioning for specific properties only

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

There are wonderful functionality for automatic versioning of documents when properties is updated. For that is needed to add the aspect `cm:versionable` and set its property `cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps` to `true`.

This behavior works perfectly, but I'm interested in the ability to filtering properties. For example, there are some metadata, editing of which should not create a new version.

Is it possible to configure it somehow?... What web scripts do I need to look at to create my own AMP- customization?...

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

---

I'm trying to override the versionable aspect, as described [here](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4821-versioning-behaviour) (see "*Versionable aspect config*"), but get the following exception:

```
 2017-07-11 20:05:07,117  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-8080-exec-2] Exception from executeScript: 06110023 Failed to execute transaction-level behaviour public abstract void org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies$OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.onUpdateProperties(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,java.util.Map,java.util.Map) in transaction a83f6f64-95cc-42da-83bc-1780f37993fc
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06110023 Failed to execute transaction-level behaviour public abstract void org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies$OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.onUpdateProperties(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,java.util.Map,java.util.Map) in transaction a83f6f64-95cc-42da-83bc-1780f37993fc
        at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.execute(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:262)
        at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.beforeCommit(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:141)
        at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(TransactionSupportUtil.java:535)
        at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(TransactionSupportUtil.java:514)
        at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.beforeCommit(TransactionSupportUtil.java:479)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:925)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:738)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
        at org.alfresco.util.transaction.SpringAwareUserTransaction.commit(SpringAwareUserTransaction.java:482)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:486)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:587)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:656)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:428)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:308)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.module.aosmodule.service.ContextRootFilter.doFilter(ContextRootFilter.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:174)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:132)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.alfresco.repo.version.VersionableAspect.onUpdateProperties(VersionableAspect.java:445)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour$JavaMethodInvocationHandler.invoke(JavaBehaviour.java:181)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.onUpdateProperties(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor473.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.execute(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:250)
        ... 79 more
```

Comment: I think you'll need to write a custom Behaviour in Java which listens for the OnUpdate event, checks the changed properties and versions if wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible OTB.

I haven't tried it myself, but there's a property called `excludedOnUpdateProps` (Java bean defined, though), described here:

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4821-versioning-behaviour

If you're going to try it out, I'd appreciate feedback on whether it actually works.

Comment: Find how the bean is defined by default in your version of Alfresco. I believe the default version has *lockService* set, and the example you're following does not (it's probably for an older version of Alfresco)

https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/version/VersionableAspect.java